# How can I customize the filter of the product grid on the admin side in order to filter by RANGE?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Hope you are all good and in great shape.

TLDR: How can I filter my product grid on the admin side using a WEIGHT RANGE?

I am a newbie in Magento and I have been doing some progress over the last months on the basics of customizing Magento to our small company. I had a request from the sales team which I am struggling to get to term. We sell a kind of product which has a different weight to every item and the final price of the product is calculated by multiplying a variable rate by the weight. It makes the weight a very important attribute in the system not only for the sales/logistics, but also for the client's decision making. Therefore, I need to filter the product catalog grid on the admin side by weight, but not by a specific number, instead, I need a RANGE of weight. (From ...kg to ...kg) I managed to create the field, but I am struggling on the part were the action happens. Please take a look on the screenshots below:

**Weight range in filters**
[image]

**Weight in columns**

[image]

This is the structure of the module that I created:

**module structure**

[image]

And here is the code on the file AddWeightFieldToCollection.php which I am struggling with:

```
<?php

namespace Diamwill\WeightFilter\Ui\DataProvider\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface;

class AddWeightFieldToCollection implements AddFieldToCollectionInterface

{

    public function addField(Collection $collection, $field, $alias = null)

    {

      $mg_eav_attribute = $collection->getResource()->getTable('mg_eav_attribute');
      $mg_catalog_product_entity_decimal = $collection->getResource()->getTable('mg_catalog_product_entity_decimal');
      $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
          ['soa' => $mg_eav_attribute],
          'soa.entity_type_id = 4 AND soa.attribute_code = \'weight\'',
          null
      );
      $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
          ['dcrt' => $mg_catalog_product_entity_decimal],
          'soa.attribute_id = dcrt.attribute_id',
          ['code']
      );

        $collection->joinField(

            'weight_range',

            'mg_catalog_product_entity',

            'value',

            'mg_catalog_product_entity.entity_id = soa.entity_id AND soa.store_id = 0',

            null,

            'left'

        );

    }

}
```

Basically, I know that I have to join the product tables to get weight, which in SQL terms would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    w1.value AS 'weight'
FROM
    mg_catalog_product_entity AS prod
        LEFT JOIN
            mg_catalog_product_entity_decimal w1 ON 
                prod.entity_id = w1.entity_id
                AND w1.store_id = 0
                AND w1.attribute_id = (SELECT 
                        attribute_id
                    FROM
                        mg_eav_attribute
                    WHERE
                        attribute_code = 'weight'
                            AND entity_type_id = (SELECT 
                                entity_type_id
                            FROM
                                mg_eav_entity_type
                            WHERE
                                entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'));
```

Which I am not capable of linking with the Collection class and apply to the column, in order to filter. Can someone help me with the code? I am happy to read a tutorial to learn or to get a certain book/article with more information on the topic.

Please, I do not want to buy a plugin/module in order to do that. I would like to learn how to do it.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Have a great day!

Comment: With this you can set custom attributes, just as you would, say, *"shirt size"*. So widget_1 would have it's own SKU.  You set 3 attributes under that specific product with different prices.  Same as you would `small = $1`, `medium = $2`, `large = $3` --  Instead of small, med large, the labels would read `1kg = $1`, `2kg = $2` etc etc etc .. each will have it's own SKU.  If it sound's like a lot of work, it is.  And from someone who worked with a $50M / Year Magento store .. You're going to want to do this in an excel sheet and import the products by the thousands rather than 1-at-a-time.

Comment: [THIS EXTENSION](https://unirgy.com/urapidflow) Will save your sales team (or whoever enters the products) a TON of time .. Thus saving the company $

Comment: Hi @Zak, as I said before, I am not asking advice on a plugin to buy. I would like to know how to do it. Also, that approach on fixed ranges of weight doesn't really solve my problem because my products have a FLOAT like weights, for example 1.23kg, 0.72kg and so on. Thank you very much for your inputs anyway.